# Converse of Ito's formula

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

Let $f,h,g$ be continuous functions and $B$ a real Brownian motion. We suppose that a.s. $$\forall u \in \mathbb{R}_+,f(B_u)=f(B_0)+\int_0^ug(B_r)dB_r+\frac{1}{2}\int_0^uh(B_r)dr.$$

Prove that $f$ is a $C^2$-function, $f'=g$ and $f''=h.$

It seems this is a converse of Ito's formula.

Do you know how to prove it? What is the equivalent of this and the proof when we consider $q$-dimensional Brownian motion?

Attempt: we can suppose $B$ bounded by $c$, otherwise, we localize, $f$ is continuous, therefore there exists $(f_k)_k$ of class $C^2$ converging uniformly to $f$ on compacts, applying Ito's formula we find that $$\forall u \in \mathbb{R}_+,f_k(B_u)=f_k(B_0)+\int_0^uf'_k(B_r)dB_r+\frac{1}{2}\int_0^uf''_k(B_r)dr.$$ and $\int_0^uf'_k(B_r)dB_r+\frac{1}{2}\int_0^uf''_k(B_r)dr$ converges to $\int_0^ug(B_r)dB_r+\frac{1}{2}\int_0^uh(B_r)dr.$

How to continue, is a way to prove that $f'$ converges uniformly to $g$? De we also need to approximate it?

Comment: Partial answer: When $f$ is a $C^2$-function then by Ito's formula
$$
f(B_u)=f(B_0)+\int_0^uf'(B_r)\,dB_r+\frac{1}{2}\int_0^uf''(B_r)\,dr.
$$
Now apply the uniqueness of the continuous semimartingale [decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semimartingale#Continuous_semimartingales).

Comment: You need to prove $f$ is $C^2$

Comment: No. Some homework wants *you* to prove it. Any thoughts?

Comment: This is not a Homework! How about localizing and approximating $f$ with functions of class $C^2$

Comment: You may want to give a reference where that claim is made.

Comment: What's the reference for this claim?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A start:** Let $H$ be a primitive of $h$, and $K$ a primitive of $H$. That is, $H'(x)=h(x)$ for all $x$, and $K'(x) = H(x)$ for all $x$. Use Ito to check that $f(B_t) - K(B_t)$ is a (continuous) local martingale. From this it follows that $K-f$ must have the form $x\mapsto a+bx$ for some real constants $a$ and $b$.

Comment: I am havinh troubles with the last part. How to prove that $K-f$ is linear? We can localize to have a bounded martingale.

Comment: Is it possible to relax the continuity of functions? What about the $q$-dimensiinal case?

Comment: Fix reals $l<r$ and let $x\in(l,r)$. By considering the first exit time of $B$ from $(l.r)$ after the first hitting time of $x$, you can show that
$$
\varphi(x) = {r-x\over r-l}\varphi(A)+{x-l\over r-l}\varphi(B).
$$
where $\varphi=K-f$. This shows that $K-f$ is linear on $(l,r)$; vary $l$ and $r$ to finish.

One can weaken the condition on $h$ to local integrability (rather than continuity); the conclusion will then be that $g$ is locally absolutely continuous and $g'=h$ a.e.

Comment: Thanks! I can see how to handle the 1-dimensional case. Any thoughts on the multi-dimensional version?

Comment: I'm guessing the multi-dimensional result is true but harder to prove—antiderivatives are a dodgier item in higher dimensions.

Comment: In the higher dimension we will obtain poisson equation, by considering the first exit time from a ball, therefore we need to solve the equation on a (for example unit) ball, is it possible to obtain a solution?

Comment: I found a solution using stochastic calculus in Peres book: https://people.bath.ac.uk/maspm/book.pdf all what we need is "one solution" to to do the proof

Comment: More precisely, I expect that modulo smoothness of $f$ (and exceptional sets), one should have that $\nabla f-g$ is divergence free and that $h=\Delta f$. 

What is the source of this question?

Comment: I found it here (final): https://www.math.ucla.edu/~biskup/275d.1.21f/

Comment: But the dimensional case (generalization) should be the same, if we find a solution for the Poisson equation, as given in Peres book. Right?

Comment: Yes to the "find a solution to Poisson equation". FOr then is $\Delta u=h$ you'll have that $f-u$ is harmonic, so $f$ is smooth and Ito applies.

Comment: I noticed that you suggested a solution for this equation, can you provide more details how to prove it's a solution?