# Solution for the Poisson problem

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, partial-differential-equations, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

Consider a continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}^q \to \mathbb{R}$.

I woukd like to check if there are any analytical or probabilistic way to find a function $h:\mathbb{R}^q \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\Delta h=f$ on $B(0,1).$

Reference are also appreciated.

Comment: If you don't care about boundary conditions/uniqueness, the usual way of doing this is convolving with the fundamental solution of the laplacian. You might also want to search for Green's functions. As a technical aside, $f$ continuous, as it turns out, is not enough to guarantee that $h\in C^2$ (you only get slightly less).

Comment: $h$ is $C^2$ is an extra assumption. I am interested in finding a $h$ verifying the equation. Uniqueness also doesn't matter.

Comment: [Poisson Kernel](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PoissonKernel.html)

Comment: Not for any continuous function $f$ there is a function $u\in C^2$ s.t. $\Delta h=f$. The sufficient condition is $f$ to be Holder continuous.

Answer (score 1):

Let $B$ be a $q$-dimensional standard Brownian motion, and let $T:=\inf\{t>0: |B_t|=2\}$. Then
$$
h(x):=\Bbb E^x\left[\int_0^T f(B_t)\,dt\right],\qquad x\in B(0,1),
$$
should do the job for you. The superscript $x$ on $\Bbb E^x$ is to indicate that the Brownian motion starts at $x$.

Comment: How can we prove that the $\Delta h=f$? (The above question is related to the one asked before https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4590803/converse-of-itos-formula/4592173?noredirect=1#comment9673930_4592173). In Peres book he suppose that the function should be Holder continuous to obtain a solution. But here we are only supposing $f$ continuous.

Comment: It seems there is an error, If we considered $q=1=f,$ then we obtain that $h(x)=4-x^2,h''(x)=-2$