# Brownian motion and Laplacian of a function

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous and $T:=\inf\{r>0,|B_r|=2\},$ where $|.|$ is the Euclidean norm.

Let $h(x)= E_x[\int_0^T f(B_r)dr], x\in B(0,1).$

Can we claim that for $x \in B(0,1),\Delta h(x)=f(x)?$ Why?

I tried the way used in Dirichlet's problem to do the proof with no sucess.

The question is related to: [Solution for the Poisson problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4594140/solution-for-the-poisson-problem)

Comment: Problem 4.2.25 in Karatzas and Shreve's book "Brownian motion and Stochastic Calculus" might be helpful.

Comment: Here we are trying to prove the converse of that problem

Comment: Why do you consider $B(0,2)$ and $B(0,1)$? Also: you need a boundary condition for $h$. Is it zero? Further details on this theorem of Kakutani you can find [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_processes_and_boundary_value_problems) including references.

Answer (score 1):

According to Problem 4.2.25 in [1] (thanks Kazuki OKAMURA for pointing that out):

> *Consider an open bounded subset $D$ of $\mathbb{R}^d$ and the bounded continuous functions $g:D\to\mathbb{R}$ and $f:\partial D\to\mathbb R$. Assume that $u:\overline{D}\to\mathbb R$ is continuous of class $C^2(D)\,,$ and solves the Poisson equation
> $$\tag{1}
> \textstyle\frac{1}{2}\Delta u=-g\,;\text{ in }D
> $$
> subject to the boundary condition $u=f$ on $\partial D\,.$*
>
> *Then the representation
> $$\tag{2}
> u(x)=\mathbb E^x\Big[f(W_{\tau_d})+\int_0^{\tau_D}g(W_t)\,dt\Big]\,;\quad x\in D
> $$
> holds. (Here $W$ is a Brownian motion starting in $x$ and $\tau_D=\inf\{t\ge 0:W_t\in D^c\}$ is its exit time from $D\,.$)*

- This is a modern formulation of a famous Theorem first proved by
  [S. Kakutani](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_processes_and_boundary_value_problems).
- You want to prove the converse.
  That is: Does a function $h(x)$ defined by the RHS of (2) satisfy the Poisson equation $\frac{1}{2}\Delta h=-g$ and the boundary condition $h=f$ on $\partial D\,?$
- The answer is yes provided that it is properly formulated.
- First, it follows from the [maximum principle](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2936061/949989) that the solution $u$ in  K&S' Problem 4.2.25 in [1] is unique. This implies

***Corollary*** to Problem 4.2.25 in [1]: *Let
$$\tag{3}
h(x):=\mathbb E^x\Big[f(W_{\tau_d})+\int_0^{\tau_D}g(W_t)\,dt\Big]
$$
and assume that the BVP for $u$ above has a solution. Then $h(x)$ is that solution.*

***Remarks***

- We can always define $h(x)$ by (3) but without making further assumptions on the regularity of $D$ and on the functions $f$ and $g$ we cannot guarantee that the BVP has a solution. For instance when $\partial D$ has the famous Lebesgue 'cusp' that is also discussed in [1] in their proof of Theorem 4.2.12 then we can modify $f$ at that cusp $x$ without changing $h$ because the BM never reaches that boundary point.
- In short: the formulation of Problem 4.2.25 is the most economic one to guarantee the converse in the sense of the above simple Corollary.

[1] I. Karatzas, S. Shreve, *Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus*.

Comment: Your $f$ is a $g$ in my answer and in K&S. The boundary condition is something else: it is $f$ in K&S and in my answer and unclear in your question.

Comment: Sorry, there is no boundary condition in this problem, my initial problem how to verify that $h(x)=E_x[\int_0^T f(B_r)dr]$ satisfies $\Delta h =f$?

Comment: Your exit time $T$ is that of $D=B(0,\color{red}{2})\,.$ Your $h$ satisfies for this $D$ the boundary condition $h=0$ on $\partial D\,.$ Apply my Corollary and you are done.

Comment: If $u$ is a solution for our problem then it satisfies $(2),$ what about the converse ? This is where I am struggling, can you provide a proof for your corollary?

Comment: The proof is *uniqueness* of the solution for which I gave a link to maximum principle PLUS the additional assumption you need to make that that $u$ *exists*. That nails the Corollary down. To get existence you can use Jose27's first comment in that [related question of yours](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4594140/solution-for-the-poisson-problem). Also follow K.defaiote's [Poisson kernel link](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PoissonKernel.html).